# xPage viewPanel with "Search in view results" "Sort column" only descending Sort

Tags: xpages

This appears to presented sorted items only in descending order.

Any ideas?

Is this a known bug in 8.5.3?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the columns that you want to be sortable have the design property:

`Click on column header to sort: Both`